# 2D php array into an HTML table

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

How can I achieve with a PHP array, to have as result in an html table the following result:

```
Server1          db_1

Server1          db_2

Server1          db_3

Server2          db_1

Server2          db_2

Server3          db_3
```

Comment: I started as it follows $servers = array(Server1=>array('db_1','db_2','db_3'),Server2=>array('db_1','db_2','db_3'),
); but I don't know how to loop to have the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
$servers = array(
    'Server 1' => array(
        'db_1',
        'db_2',
        'db_3'
    ),
    'Server 2' => array(
        'db_1',
        'db_2'
    ),
    'Server 3' => array(
        'db_3'
    )
);
echo '<table>';
foreach($servers as $server=>$dbs)
{
    foreach($dbs as $db)
    {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$server.'</td><td>'.$db.'</td></tr>';
    }
}
echo '</table>';
```